# Control plus/minus affect only current window

Tags: jquery, css, popup, window

I have a link that displays a window popup. I realize that when doing ctrl- (or ctrl+) it zooms out (or in) such window and also all of its parent and siblings (other windows opened from another links).

Is there a way to affect only the current window?

Comment: This is pretty much browser based... AFAIK webkit (and webkit origin) browsers probably save the zoom percentage for the whole domain

Comment: Because Chrome sets it for the entire domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Vanilla Javascript Bookmarlet for document scaling. (Zoom in/Zoom out)

This actually gave me an idea... Crossbrowser solution could be a **Javascript bookmarklet**.

```
javascript:var HtmlES=document.documentElement.style;setTimeout(function(){HtmlES.transform = "scale(" + (prompt("Enter zoom level in %", "100") / 100) + ")";HtmlES.transformOrigin = "top";},10);
```

**Just create a new bookmark with this javascript oneliner as URL address.**

It adds transform scale to the html element and rendering everything scaled.

PS: Timeout is for chrome - for some reason without timetout, it completely messes up HTML DOM from time to time.

Comment: It's a nice solution.

However, the problem here is that it asks the scale at the beginning, but user may want to change it afterwards.

I will take your idea, and do a scale but when clicking some element:
a "+" button will scale positive (current scale + 0.1) and a "-" button will do a negative scale (current scale - 0.1).

Thanks.

Comment: @Mundo you're welcome... Feel free to remix my code. By the way, i changed it from js eval to anonymous funciton - some websites are set to prevent js eval.

Comment: @Mundo By the way you could also use browser memory to temporarirly store the zoom value for specific page on domain, so everytime you trigger the script, it would scale to remembered value.